# XSLT check needed please

Tags: xml, xslt

### XML given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <sensor-system>
     <velocity>120.00</velocity>    <!-- km/h --> 

     <temperature location="inside">24.6</temperature> 
     <temperature location="outside">-12.5</temperature> 

     <seats>

       <seat location="front">
               <id>1</id> 
                <temperature>32.5</temperature>
               <heating-is-on/>

       </seat>

       <seat location="back">
               <id>2</id>
                <temperature>23.5</temperature> 
        </seat>

     </seats>
   </sensor-system>
```

### Required :

d) XSLT (25 Points)
Write an XSL transformation that receives the given XML as input and puts out text with all seat id numbers where the temperature of the corresponding seat is less than the inside temperature and the heating is swiched off.
The output for the given XML should look as follows:
Cold seats with heating switched off: 2 (23.5)
The first number is the seat id, the second is the temperature of the seat.

My answer please check :

---

```
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:for-each select="/sensor-system/seats/seat/temperature">
             <xsl:if  test="(temperature < /sesnsor-system/temperature[@location="inside"]) | not(/sensor-system/seats/seat/heating-is-on)" >

                <xsl:value-of select="concat('cold seats with heating switched of : ' , '',/sensor-system/seats/seat/id,'(,/sensor-system/seats/seat/temperature,')')/>

           </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main bugs in your attempt are:

- Iterating through temperatures and then referencing `temperature` from that context
- Using `<` instead of `&lt;`
- Misspelling `sensor-system`
- Using double-quotes inside double-quotes
- Using `|` instead of `and`
- Using an absolute path for `heating-is-on`, `id`, and `temperature` instead of relative paths
- Missing closing apostrophe after the `(` in the `value-of`
- Missing closing quotation at the end of the `value-of`

Here's how you can do this with `for-each` and `if`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="insideTemp" 
                  select="/sensor-system/temperature[@location='inside']" />

    <xsl:text>cold seats with heating switched off: </xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="/sensor-system/seats/seat">
      <xsl:if  test="temperature &lt; $insideTemp and not(heating-is-on)" >
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(id, ' (', temperature, ') ')" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With a predicate in the `for-each`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="insideTemp"
                  select="/sensor-system/temperature[@location='inside']" />

    <xsl:text>cold seats with heating switched off: </xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="/sensor-system/seats/seat[temperature &lt; $insideTemp and 
                                                       not(heating-is-on)]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(id, ' (', temperature, ') ')" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="insideTemp" 
                  select="/sensor-system/temperature[@location='inside']" />

    <xsl:text>cold seats with heating switched off: </xsl:text>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="/sensor-system/seats/seat
                         [temperature &lt; $insideTemp and not(heating-is-on)]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="seat">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(id, ' (', temperature, ') ')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select="/sensor-system/seats/seat">

   <xsl:if test="temperature &lt; /sensor-system/temperature[@location='inside'] or not(heating-is-on) " >
    <xsl:text>cold seats with heating switched of : </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="id"/> <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="temperature"/>
    <xsl:text> 
</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```